# Unable to use Javascript Library in Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, ecmascript-6

I want to log all the events from a midi file.
I found a library that should do just that:
[text](https://github.com/grimmdude/MidiPlayerJS)

Problem is I can't figure out how to use it in a website.
I've tried with a CDN from jsdeliver, however I get the error: "loadFile is only supported on Node.js"

I've tried with npm and vite build, however I still get the same error. The library uses the following code[image: Code]

This library has 350 stars and seems like it should be of good quality,
If you could help me figure out how to correctly use it in a web project, that would be great. (in the browser)

Right now, I'm using the ES6 import:[image]

Not sure how I can use nodejs in the browser, or if there is something I can do to fix this, is this the fault of the library?

I can perfectly fine import local files for Threejs (for example) within the same project. Not sure why this dosen't work...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please, do not post screenshots of your code. [This is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please, edit your question, and post the code as text.

Comment: [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/about) is not used in browsers. It's a runtime used on the server.

Comment: Then how is the library supposed to be used, there are examples of it being used on websites?

Comment: You can't use `loadFile` function in the browser. In the [demo](https://github.com/grimmdude/MidiPlayerJS/blob/master/demo/js/app.js) they use `loadArrayBuffer` instead

Comment: If you want to write logs created by a browser client to a file on your server you need to create an endpoint for submitting updates to the log. There are plenty of client specific ways to dynamically load a text file stored on your server but you can't write to it directly.